# Is it possible to write a procedure in vb6 that accepts bracketed arguments

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I am trying to write a replacement for the circle method in vb6.
Its syntax is :

> object.Circle [Step] (x, y), radius, [color, start, end, aspect]

So a call to it could look like :

```
Me.Circle (100, 100), 60
```

I have been unable to figure out a way of writing a procedure so that a call to it will
accept parentheses used in this way.

Comment: Simple answer: You can't.

Comment: @roger_rowland, Pity, your quick reply suggests that you have come across this before. Thanks btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Circle` keyword, along with `Print`, `PSet`, and a handful of others are not the real methods. Their syntax is handled by the compiler and converted to real method calls.
Unfortunately, the VB6 IDE offers no way of emulating these methods.

The unusual signatures are used for compatibility with earlier versions and date from QBasic

Comment: They're pseudo-methods that are compiled as special statements.  The arguments get gathered up and the "real" (internal) method gets called.

Comment: @Bob77 and Deanna Thanks for the detailed explanations.

Comment: Historical note: the `Circle` unusual syntax and that of other similar methods/statements is not because these have a bizarre syntax requirement, but simply out of backward compatibility. The syntax was originally developed for MSBASIC in the 70's. At the time, BASIC didn't support methods, custom functions or anything with custom arguments so there was no reason to use a regular syntax. Since BASIC was intended for beginners, using a non-regular syntax that was easier to understand was the correct choice. Had these statements been added later, they likely would use a normal method syntax.